# Landscape use StartSSL Cert for registering clients

Tags: ssl, landscape

I currently have a standalone landscape server and I am trying to mage the message-system use a startssl so that I do not have to install a self signed CA cert. My goal is to allow my computers to register without the need to install a CA cert on the box. However all the guides that I can find use a cert created by a manually created CA. Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean 'startssl'?